# Accessing the public variable of class library from 2 different application

Tags: c#, public, class-library

I have a class library developed in c# which has something similar as shown below. It has a class `ClassLib`. It has one public variable `somevariable` and 2 methods.One method assigns the value to this variable and one method uses this variable.

```
class ClassLib
{
    public string somevariable;
    public void SomeMethod1()
    {
        somevariable = "someData";
    }
    public void SomeMethod2()
    {
        string finalValue = somevariable;
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 different windows services, in which this class library is being referenced to.

In **Windows Service 1** , it has some similar code.

```
public class Application1
{
    public void AppMethod1()
    {
        ClassLib c1 = new ClassLib();
        c1.somevariable = "Application 1 Data";
        c1.SomeMethod2();
    }
}
```

This class is assigning the value to the public variable and calling the second method to use it.

**Windows Service 2 :**

```
public class Application2
{
    public void AppMethod2()
    {
        ClassLib c1 = new ClassLib();
        c1.SomeMethod1();
        c1.SomeMethod2();
    }
}
```

This calls both the methods.
These 2 windows services run continuously.So now my question is, if both services are running simultaneously and referencing to same class in class library, will this effect the value of `somevariable`. Since one application is assigning the value and one is trying to use the existing value from `SomeMethod1`.
In other words, in WindowsService2 , when `c1.SomeMethod2()` is called, will the value of `somevariable` be `"Application 1 Data"` at any point of time? Will the values overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each Windows Service runs as its own process, meaning it has its own heap. So there is no shared memory between the two services, even though they reference the same DLL.

There are ways to create data that are shared between processes, but only if the code does something unusual. Normal variables are not shared.